# How to pass an "EditText" value between activities Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-edittext

I'm tring to build an activity where I insert a search word in an EditText, and on a click of a button, app opens a different activity, and in that activity I need to execute a query using the value of the search word that was inserted in the previous activity.

How can I move this value from previous activity and use it in another different activity?

Thank you.

Comment: Use Intent extras to pass any data to second Activity.

Comment: Best way you can do it with Intent.putExtra();

Comment: [duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

**Intent** is used for sending data from one activity to another. [More About It](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Use this to "put" the string:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);   
String searchItem= editText.getText().toString(); //Getting string from the editText, in your case the Search based EditText

i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", searchItem); // putExtra(KEY,VALUE) where KEY is used to fetch data in another activity and VALUE is the value you want to carry.

startActivity(i);
```

Then, to retrieve the value in your NextActivity, Do this in OnCreate:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null)
{
    String myParam = extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
}
else
{
    //..oops!
}
```

Comment: I would recommend rigging the key as a constant. For example: public static final String INTENT_PARAM_SEARCH_KEYWORD = "INTENT_PARAM_SEARCH_KEYWORD";

Comment: This is an example. I would rather break it down further if I have to make the answer clearer for the beginners.

Comment: Sure; that's fair enough

Answer (score 1):

Moving to next activities:

1 pass whole string to next activity by using

```
 intent.putExtras("Key",string);
```

2 make a singleton class of getter setter , by using this class you can set and get values throughout application

3 save value in db and read it from it